# Incorrect Time on File for date modified in search results

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, enterprise-search

My environment is SP 2013 On-Prem.  I have a user that states they modified a file and the properties on the file indicate that.

If I do a search (after a crawl) and look at the image preview, it shows a 7 hour difference.

If I look in the document library > ellipsis > image preview > the date/time is correct.

Crawl log shows it being successfully crawled.

- I have tested this change in a separate document in a separate site    collection and it reflects properly in the search results preview.
- I tested an existing office doc in the same doc library.  Same issue.
- I tested a new office doc in the same doc library.  Same issue.
- I tested an image in the Images library.  Shows correct timestamp.
- I created a new doc library with a new office doc.  Same issue.
- Regional settings are local and correct for each of those site collections.

I started to consider this article until I saw that the separate test was producing correct results.
http://www.sharepointsearch.net/crawled-and-filtered-office-or-pdf-documents-have-a-wrong-date-in-search-results/

Anyone have any thoughts/ideas on what I can try?  #Baffled

Comment: Are the searchers time zone and the web app time zone the same? Both have an impact on how the time is displayed in SP.

Comment: Yes, all the same time zone.  The two different site collections that I had different results in are in the same web app too.

Answer (score 0):

There are several crawled properties for saving the modified date in SharePoint. Read [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spses/2013/10/30/show-more-relevant-titles-in-search-results-in-sharepoint-2013-plus-some-other-improvements/) for more information (it also has been mentioned in your article).

For the default “Modified” column that contains the last modified date and time information in the list/library, you can move up “ows_Modified” crawl property to the top of the mappings for “LastModifiedTime” managed property. Or, you can create a managed property, map “ows_Modified” crawl property to this managed property and use this managed property instead of “LastModifiedTime” managed property in [display template](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn794247.aspx). Run a full crawl after changing managed properties or add new ones.

Besides, you can create custom manage properties, map each of these crawl properties to different manage property. Make sure the managed property is retrievable. Using a Content Search web part to see the value of each managed properties, check the differences between values of these properties.

Central Administration -> Manage Service Application -> Search Service Application -> Search schema -> Create a managed property -> Add mappings.

Comment: And that goes along with the link that I had added to my post.  Question is wouldn't that time be incorrect all the time and not some of the time?  I'm certainly keen to try.  Unfortunately the full crawl takes over 8 hours so a long time before I can determine if it worked.

Answer (score 0):

So I was forced into rebuilding the search indices.  Was getting this event every minute on one server.  I had also changed the mapping order for LastModifiedTime and I'm looking good now.  I think a big problem was search index issue.

> Log Name:  Application 
>   Event ID:  6482
>   Source:  SharePoint Server
>   Application Server Administration job failed for service instance Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance (1f48217f-956f-478d-b1b7-ec73868a95e4).
>
> Reason: An update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this
>   action. The object SearchDataAccessServiceInstance was updated by
>   \farm admin, in the OWSTIMER (8940) process, on machine
>   .  View the tracing log for more information about the
>   conflict.
>
> Technical Support Details:
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPUpdatedConcurrencyException: An
>   update conflict has occurred, and you must re-try this action. The
>   object SearchDataAccessServiceInstance was updated by \farm
>   admin, in the OWSTIMER (8940) process, on machine .  View the
>   tracing log for more information about the conflict.    at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Search.Administration.SearchServiceInstance.Synchronize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Office.Server.Administration.ApplicationServerJob.ProvisionLocalSharedServiceInstances(Boolean
>   isAdministrationServiceJob)